# Why Vue's controlled `<input />` without a handler can still type text into it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Please see this two minimum example of React and Vue

They all have an `<input />`, and bind the **input value** to the **state**.

## React

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value] = React.useState("Hello World");

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={value} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input :value="value" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        value: "Hello World",
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

If you type something into React's version input, nothing will happen.

I can understand this part because the state isn't changing, so the input value isn't changing also.

However, if you type something into Vue's version input, **you can now alter the input value**.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue's attribute bindings are one-way.

Vue also does not have [*"controlled"* components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Whenever you change the `value` data property, the `<input>` value will be updated but changing the `<input>` value directly won't alter the `value` data property.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({ value: "Hello World" })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input :value="value" />
  <pre>value = {{ value }}</pre>
  
  <p><button @click="value = `New value ${Math.random()}`">New value</button></p>
</div>
```